# In Word, Programmatically Open New Document Dialog

Tags: vba, vsto, ms-word, word-2007

I am looking for a way to programatically open the "New Document" dialog in Word 2007. It is the same one you get when you select File->New .  You can also open it using the FileNew macro or the "New..." menu command.  However, I have been unable to find a way to do this programmatically.

I have tried:

```
Application.Run MacroName:="FileNew"
```

and

```
Dialogs(wdDialogFileNew).Show
```

and

```
CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=5746).Execute
```

but both of these open the old dialog, not the new one that word 2007 uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a 'real' VBA command exists for open that dialog, I can't find it. However, I did find this utterly lame workaround via some quick googling:

```
SendKeys "%"
SendKeys "F"
SendKeys "N"
```

It does what you want though! Found it here http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32228837/new-file-dialog-in-word-2.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I found that article too.  Unfortunately, it creates that flicker as a result of the menu briefly coming up.  I'm still considering it, but I was hoping to not to have to do this.

Comment: you can always turn the flicker on/off with Application.ScreenUpdating = True/False

Comment: @Otaku Sadly, turning ScreenUpdating off doesn't help in this instance.

Comment: @Jacob Yeah, it is a bit annoying that there doesn't seem to be direct VBA access to that dialog. Just a hunch, but maybe there's a VSTO method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the Command ID for the button and execute it?

```
Dim c As CommandBarControl
Set c = CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=18)
c.Execute
```

Control ID 18 is the word application ID for the New... button.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just use:

```
Documents.Add
```

without any parameters.